# what's the meaning of warning with proxy of httpclient?

Tags: proxy, httpclient

i want to use the proxy in he program as flows:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();  
httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("192.168.0.1", 9527);  
httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
```

but the eclipse always output:

```
WARNING: Required proxy credentials not available for BASIC <any realm>@192.168.0.1:9527
WARNING: Preemptive authentication requested but no default proxy credentials available
WARNING: Required credentials not available for BASIC <any realm>@www.google.com:80
WARNING: Preemptive authentication requested but no default credentials available
```

why ? can you help me ? thanks.